# Transforming a polynomial with complex roots with a function of angle(root)

Tags: polynomials, roots, transformation

Although I have a PhD in Electrical Engineering I am not a mathematician and here is a problem I cannot solve on my own. I would really appreciate your help.

For calculating dedicated audio filters my goal is to transform a very long polynomial (64k coefficients) in a certain way (see below) without factorizing it. There are certain transformations well known (please see here https://brilliant.org/wiki/transforming-roots-of-polynomial/) but all of them did not cover my problem.

Let us assume that the existing polynomial has real and conjugate complex roots $r_n$. The roots can be found inside and outside the unit circle but none of them is on the unit circle so $\lvert r_n \rvert \neq 1$.

I want to scale the roots $r_n$ by a factor $f \leq 1$ shifting them towards the center of the unit circle. This means that $r_n’= f\cdot r_n$. Now the challenge is that $f$ is not constant but a function of $\arg(r_n)$ so $r_n’ = f(\arg(r_n)) \cdot r_n$.

$f(\arg(r_n))$ is decreasing in $\arg(r_n)$. This means for $\arg(r_n)=0$ $f=1$ and between $0<\arg(r_n)\leq \pi/2$, $f$ becomes smaller the bigger $\arg(r_n)$ gets.

This means roots with a small $\arg(r)$ are shifted slightly towards zero, roots with a bigger $\arg(r)$ will be shifted stronger. Any idea how this can be achieved without factorizing?
Thanks a lot
Best Charly

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Is $f$ given? If not, are there any properties it should satisfy?

Comment: Why does the part about resultants at the end not solve your problem? You apparently are solving a physical problem, and therefore are not constrained by a need for infinite accuracy (there is no such thing in physical problems). Rational functions can approximate any continuous function on a bounded domain. So you should always be able to find a rational approximation for $f$. You should in theory be able to solve your problem this way. In practice ... You are dealing with an insanely large polynomial, and your rational function may be large as well, so speed may be a serious problem.

Comment: Paul, thanks for your hint. As you wrote it is a physical problem and yes infinite accuracy is not necessary. Using the Rational will lead to a 64kx64k matrix where det has to be computed. This is really a challenge on a small PC running Scilab that I have to use.

Comment: Posilon, thanks for your commant. Yes, f is given. I will look it up during the next days and send the formula.

Comment: WimC, thank`s a lot for editing. I am a newbee with no idea of formatting ;-)

Comment: @Poslion, this is the formula for f. There is a constant MAXQ that can be changed.  
            MAXQ = 15;  
            ceta = 1/(2*MAXQ);  
            phiRes = atan(imag(myRoot),real(myRoot));  
            f = abs(exp(((phiRes)*(-ceta+%i*sqrt(1-ceta^2)))));

Comment: @Poslion: This is how the f looks like depending on ceta and phiRes if the abs(myRoot)=1: [link]http://www2.ensc.sfu.ca/people/faculty/saif/ctm/extras/dtrans.html